# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'num'

Tags: python

I started to learn Python 2 weeks ago, and I was doing an exercise about class (which consists of creating my own "Fraction" class) when I got the error in the title.
Why ? And how to solve it ? Sorry, i'm not the type of person who often ask for help, but now I really don't know how to solve it. It seems that the error occurs only in "**str**" method.

Here you have my code(idk if this will appear properly..):

```
from math import gcd

class Fraction :

    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.num = a
        self.den = b

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.num)+" / "+str(self.den)

    def reduire(self):
        return self.num//gcd(self.num,self.den) , self.den//gcd(self.num,self.den)

frac = Fraction(30,40)
print(Fraction.__str__(Fraction.reduire(frac)))
```

Comment: `reduire` returns a tuple, and then you try to get the `num` field, and tuples don't have named fields. You probably want `reduire` to return a `Fraction`.

Comment: As a side, do you know Python 2 [is not receiving updates since 2020](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/)? If you are learning just for the sake of knowing python or learning to program, you may want to consider using Python 3.

Comment: Suggestions to slow down the learning speed - try to get the basics covered/familiar then OOP

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you call `reduire` as if it is a class/static method, but it is an *instance* method, so it is more natural to call it as `frac.reduire()`

The error comes from your call of `__str__` (which again you call as if it is a class/static method) and you pass it the value that `reduire` *returns* (a tuple) instead of the `frac` instance. The `__str__` function expects the `fraq` instance (`self`) as argument. This can be done better with `str(fraq)`, in a separate statement.

But as your goal is to print, this call of `str` (and `__str__`) can actually be omitted. `print` already takes care of this. So just do:

```
frac.reduire()
print(frac)  # this implicitly calls `__str__`
```